# CSS Nav bar not spanning full length

Tags: html, css

I know I've been asking a lot of questions and you guys have been great. There are two problems I'm having with my Nav.

1) First, the NAV isn't spanning the whole way. 
2) For whatever reason, under "Services", the dropdown is spanning out long enough to fit all the links,  but under "About Us", "Photo Credit" isn't.

Here's the link:
http://matthewtbrown.com/jeffandcricketquilt/index2.html

```
nav li {
    font-family: 'bitterregular';
    font-size:16px;
}

nav ul {
    background: #000; /* Old browsers */
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-table;
}

nav ul:after {
    content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
}

nav ul ul {
    display: none;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

nav ul li {
    float: left;
    color:#fff;
}

nav ul li:hover a {
    color:#FFF;
}

nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 40px;
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul ul {
    background: #FFF;
    border-radius: 0px; 
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 100%;
}

nav ul ul li {
    float: none; 
    border-top: 1px solid #444;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
    border-color:#FFF;                  
    position: relative;
    background-color:#000;
    font-size:12px;
}

nav ul ul li a {
    padding: 8px 40px;
    color:#FFF;             }   
    nav ul ul li a:hover {
    background-color:#000;
    color:#999;
}

nav ul  li a:hover {
    background-color:#000;
    color:#999;
}

nav ul ul ul {
    position: absolute; left: 100%; top:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like your `<nav>` element actually is spanning the full width, but `nav ul` is not.

Remove `display: inline-table;` and it spans the full width. This should fix the "Photo Credit" link as well.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `display: inline-table;` from the `nav ul`. This should fix both problems. :)